# Sign APK on Client Phone

Tags: java, android, apk

This is my first question on StackOverflow, and my english is poor, so please :D.  I do this just for fun.  I want to change the icon per user, letting users change the icon of the app.  I think if I want to do this, I must read the apk self, unzip it, change che drawable/icon.png and rebuild it, at last to sign.
I try some code, but failed.  The import reason is that, `package sun.securate.*` is not in Android Java framework.  I write some code to do this, but it failed-_-
Who can help me? I can share my already written code.
Help me,Please!

Answer (score 1):

Well another work around will be to create shortcut icon for Home Screen which launches the same Activity as the launcher. With this your launcher icon in drawer will be the actual one but on the home screen you will have different icon. You can also explore the idea of creating shortcut for other apps if you know the package info.

Ref:

For package info here are the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager%28%29).

```
PackageManager pkgMgr = getPackageManager();
```

For creating short cut here is the snippet (this is just for illustration):

```
    // Setting the intent class ActivityClassToLaunch you need to try PackageManager
    Intent i = new Intent(activity, ActivityClass.class);

    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);

    result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, activity.getString(R.string.app_name));

    ShortcutIconResource iconResource = null;

    iconResource = ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(activity, R.drawable.new_app_icon);

    result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

    result.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    activity.sendBroadcast(result);
```

If you just want user to change the app icon, why dont you load the icon from the SD card. And the icon that you ship with your package will be there if no icon is specified by user.

Here is the snippet that can help you.

```
onCreate(...)
  setContentView(...); 
  setFeatureDrawable(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, 
     <your_drawable>); 
....
}
```

If this does not work, try calling `setFeatureDrawable` before `setContentView`

Comment: I assume the question was about changing the icon of 3rd party APKs, not about the own app...

Comment: now i too think..but not very clear from the desc...nyways if that is the case...then its security breach.....:)

Comment: I have try the code,but it dosen't work. I want change the app icon on home screen. but in android doc file,the api function "setFeatureDrawable" is to change the icon on the left title...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the launcher icon of a signed-and-sealed APK, except through a software upgrade.

Comment: yes,so i want to change the drawable/icon.png, rebuild the apk, resign it and then to upgrade the new resigned apk.